# How to Add Comma After Every Two Words in Php

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to add Comma (,) After Two Words in the String below.

```
$mystring = "Hello Brother I am Naeem From Php College.";
$output = str_replace('', ', ', $mystring);
echo $output;
```

**Result comes like below**

Hello, Brother, I, am, Naeem, From, Php, College.

**I want to get output Like below.**

Hello Brother, I am, Naeem From, Php College.

Comment: Because your sample string is so basic, your question could be interpreted as replace every second space with a comma and space.  Perhaps improve your [mcve] by including more diverse strings and your desired results.  Will your strings ever contain commas in advance? Will non word characters appear in your strings?  This gives the desired result but does not search for words: https://3v4l.org/0YmM3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach here would be regex. Here is the code:

```
$str = 'Hello Brother I am Naeem From Php College.';
$result = preg_replace('/(\w+ \w+)( )/', '$1, ', $str);
echo $result; // output: Hello Brother, I am, Naeem From, Php College.
```

**Breakdown:**

- 1st Capturing Group `(\w+ \w+)`

  - `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - matches the character  literally (case sensitive)
  - `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- 2nd Capturing Group `( )`

  - matches the character  literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect solution, but you can try it:

```
$wordsArray = explode(' ', $mystring);
$returnedStr = '';
foreach ($wordsArray as $index => $word) {
    if($index % 2 == 1) {
        $returnedStr .= $word .', ';
        continue;
    }
    $returnedStr .= $word . ' ';
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but you need to change your code so $returnedStr = $word  is $returnedStr = $returnedStr . $word

Comment: Dear MAZux How can I get output result of your perfect soluction

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but here is my go at it:

```
$mystring = "Hello Brother I am Naeem From Php College.";

$array = explode(' ', $mystring);

$output = $array[0] . ' ';

$switch = FALSE;
for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){

if($switch === FALSE){

$output = $output . ' ' . $array[$i];

$switch = TRUE;

} else {

 $output = $output . ', ' . $array[$i];

 $switch = FALSE;

}

echo $output;  // Hello Brother, I am, Naeem From, Php College.
```

Comment: Your code is correct. But you have an error

syntax error, unexpected end of file
I got the solution below code is working fine

$mystring = "Hello Brother I am Naeem From Php College.";

$array = explode(' ', $mystring);

$output = $array[0] . ' ';

$switch = FALSE;
for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){

if($switch === FALSE){

$output = $output . ' ' . $array[$i];

$switch = TRUE;

} else {

 $output = $output . ', ' . $array[$i];

 $switch = FALSE;

}

}

echo $output;